# Specific HTTP Redirect help - "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, nginx

There are many threads about this problem. But none has my specific issue.

Intro to our setup: we run Nginx on port 80, which sits in front of Apache on port 8889.

We haven't changed anything in Nginx or Apache, and this setup has been working for a while. Which is why we're scratching our head for what happened to suddenly cause this starting this morning. We are now getting 500 errors in our website.

From looking at the log, I suppose they're not caused by Nginx but by Apache:

```
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [error] [client 100.99.98.97] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 100.99.98.97] r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
[Fri Aug 01 23:08:33 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 100.99.98.97] redirected from r->uri = /beta/actionize, referer: http://somedomain.com/acordes/2011/01/entre-palos-y-alegrias/
```

In the `.htaccess` file of this domain, we have the following code:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index index.php index.htm index.html
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php

RewriteEngine On

# If someone types just the folder name
RewriteRule ^beta$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/beta/index [L,R=301]

# If someone types the correct file, just show it
RewriteRule ^beta/(.*)$ /beta/$1 [L]

# All other URLs..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(mailman|pipermail|w3c)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/get?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The logic is simple. For all files that are .htm etc in the root, we just show them. For any URL that starts with `/beta/[xyz]` we also show the file as it exists in the hard "beta" folder in the root folder.

But for all other URLs starting with our domain, we want to forward the code to `/beta/get?` with the parameter being that part of URI.

Example, if someone types: `http://EXAMPLE.com/xyz123`, we want to actually redirect internally to: `http://EXAMPLE.com/beta/get?u=xyz123`

(Except when the words there mailman or pipermail etc, which are used for our specific mailing lists)

Just FYI, the NGINX.CONF file is as below:

```
#-------------------- START ------------------#
http {

  server_name_in_redirect       off;
  server_names_hash_max_size    10240;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024;

  gzip on;
  gzip_static           on;
  gzip_disable          "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_vary             on;
  gzip_proxied          any;
  gzip_comp_level       5;  # Not a huge compression beyond this..so save CPU cycles
  gzip_buffers          16 8k;
  gzip_http_version     1.1;
  gzip_types            text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/png image/gif image/jpeg;

  connection_pool_size        256;
  client_header_buffer_size   256k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;
  client_max_body_size        200M; 

  client_body_buffer_size       128k;
  request_pool_size             64k;
  output_buffers                16 256k;

  open_file_cache               max=5000 inactive=20s; 
  open_file_cache_valid         60s; 

  include                       mime.types;
  default_type                  application/octet-stream;

  error_log                     logs/error.log warn;
  access_log                    off;
  server_tokens                 off; 
  autoindex                     off; 
  sendfile                      off;
  ignore_invalid_headers        on;    # Malware protection
  reset_timedout_connection     on;    # DDoS protection

  # Timeouts
  client_header_timeout         5;
  client_body_timeout           50;
  send_timeout                  50;
  keepalive_timeout             65;   # No need for default 65, but having some keepalive speeds things up
  resolver_timeout              1s;

  proxy_cache_path /dev/shm/proxy_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=proxyone:200m inactive=1h max_size=2g;
  proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$request_uri$cookie___snippa$cookie___sniplang";

  proxy_cache             proxyone;
  proxy_cache_min_uses    5;         
  proxy_cache_valid       any 60s;   
  proxy_cache_valid       200 1m; 
  proxy_cache_valid       404 0s;    
  proxy_cache_valid       410 90d;   
  proxy_cache_valid       500 502 503 504 1s;

  proxy_cache_valid       301 60m;
  proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;


set_real_ip_from   192.168.1.0/24;
set_real_ip_from   192.168.2.1;
set_real_ip_from   127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header     X-Real-IP;


  server
  {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    listen 74.86.191.114:80;
    listen 100.99.98.97:80;
    listen 75.126.161.225:80;
    listen 75.126.161.226:80;
    listen 10.17.32.66:80;

    server_name     EXAMPLE.com   www.EXAMPLE.com;

    root /home/EXAMPLE/public_html;
    index index.htm index.php index index.htm;

    error_page 403 = @backend;
    error_page 404 = @backend;
    error_page 405 = @backend;
    error_page 406 = @backend;
    error_page 500 = @backend;
    error_page 501 = @backend;
    error_page 502 = @backend;
    error_page 503 = @backend;
    error_page 504 = @backend;
    error_page 505 = @backend;


    # IMPORTANT FILES 
    location = /\.htaccess        { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.ht              { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /favicon.ico       { log_not_found off; access_log off; expires  max; }
    location = /robots.txt        { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off; expires  max; }
    location = /sitemap.gz        { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off; expires  max; }
    location = /crossdomain.xml   { allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off; expires  max; }


    location / {

      location ~.*\.(gif|jpg|png|ico|swf|rss|xml|htm|txt|js|css|gz|doc|xls|pdf|html|woff|eot|svg)$   {
        expires         max;
        try_files       $uri    @backend;
        log_not_found   off; 
      }

      proxy_pass http://100.99.98.97:8889;
      include proxy.inc;
    }

    location @backend {
      internal;
      proxy_pass http://100.99.98.97:8889;
      include proxy.inc;
    }

  }  # End of EXAMPLE.COM server block 


} # End of http block
```

What might be causing this? The `loglevel debug` in apache doesn't seem to be helping much. Much appreciate any advice or pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rules are causing a loop. The rewrite engine re-applies all the rules over and over again until the URI stops changing. Try adding some more restirctions:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index index.php index.htm index.html
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php

RewriteEngine On

# If someone types just the folder name
RewriteRule ^beta/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/beta/index [L,R=301]

# If someone types the correct file, just show it
RewriteRule ^beta/(.+)$ /beta/$1 [L]

# All other URLs..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(mailman|pipermail|w3c|beta)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/get?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Namely, an optional `/` at the end of just `/beta`, a `+` instead of a `*` to ensure there is at least one character after the `/`, and add `beta` to the conditions for the last rule.

Comment: Thank you. I am moving these to `httpd.conf` now instead of .htaccess. Would it be alright to add a "/" in front of all the RewriteRules here?

Comment: Yes, in a nondirectory baded rules need a / in front